# AspNetCore EF6 Identity Shared Cookie Authentication between apps

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I want to set up multiple webapps in my domain. I am using VS2022 solution with multiple projects and shared class libraries to keep things together.

I would prefer that if I log in into the app, and navigate to any of the others, I would also be logged in into that app automatically, and off course logging out, the same effect.

At the moment, I can log into app 1, go to app 2 and log in there, but when I return to app  1 I am logged out.

Currently in my startup I have the following

```
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "AspNet.SharedCookie";
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost"; // "*.example.com";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax; 
            });
            services.AddAuthentication("AspNet.SharedCookie");
```

Identity platform is `Microsoft.Identity` from sql server. I dont think there is any issue there as I am succesfully loggin in/out everywhere.

```
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

My apps running currently localhost:1000, localhost:2000, localhost:3000 etc but this would eventually become app1.example.com, app2.example.com etc.

The `AspNet.SharedCookie` is available on all sites, but obviously changes based on the current app.

I even though changing the app Id but I dont think thats a good idea, besides, had no effect.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-DEV.app1-USE THIS SAME ID IN ALL APPS</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

How do I get this right to keep all apps standard with there own log in identity, but switching apps should keep that login info?

Comment: The issue sound your share cookie between multiple application not working. And I think it should not related to `UserSecretsId`. Could you share your startup.cs files in your two applications, so that we can reproduce the issue in our side, or you can provide the link which you refered.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I also didn't think it would but tried as last resort.

Comment: Sorry I only reply now, I extracted the nessassry bits and created a git repo for this. It's my first time I use git so another learning process. Any way, I got it here https://github.com/CConXAdmin/SharedAppCookie. Would appreciate any comments or feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your sharing, and I solve the issue by adding the code below.

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp-keys")).SetApplicationName("testapp");
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

**My Code**

[image]