# Login with load balancer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

My application works, after switching to a load balancer server, the claim works sometimes and sometimes not.

This is in .NET Core 6:

```
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Cadastro");
    o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    o.SlidingExpiration = true;
    var defaultCallback = o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin;
    o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.RedirectUri = "/Login";
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);

        return defaultCallback(context);
    };
});
```

I've changed the settings several times, none of which resolved it.

Comment: Welcome! First are the servers running IIS, and if so, have the Machine Keys all been set to be identical?

Comment: Try to use `builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.1.100\\temp-keys")).SetApplicationName("testapp");` to save the information. For more details, you can [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74442508/7687666).